# How to structure survey data?

Tags: mysql, winforms, survey

Note: this is NOT like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534737/best-way-to-store-survey-data)

I've been tasked to construct a survey that our customer service people can use to get info from our customers about our service etc.

My question is how to store the questions/answers in the db where the questions are stored like so:

- boolean question1

  - if (false): string question2 (typically the reason why question1 was false)

This would be easy, however the questions can be nested multiple levels:

- boolean question1

  - if (false) boolean question2

    - if (true) string question3
    - if (false) string question4

If I didn't have to store it in the db, I would represent the questions (and indeed the whole survey) as a composite, but I don't know how I'd store something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your questions form a tree, and not a graph, there are two common ways to [represent hierarchical data in sql](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/).

The **Adjacency List Model model** requires repeated self-joins to look up children (of children ... of children). If you have an ORM, like Hibernate, the ORM will take care of doing sufficient self-joins to bring back a question and its child answers. Without an ORM to do that, you'll have to either dynamically add self-joins to a query, or do multiple queries, one for each row in the previous result set.

The **Nested Set Model**, usually attributed to Joe Celko, allows you to get a whole tree in a single select. But it means that adding and deleting nodes is more complicated, requiring updates to all rows.

In Adjacency List, you could have a question table like this `(id, question text, id_next_if_true, id_next_if_false)`. This departs from the classical Adjacency List, in that instead of children holding the parent_id, the parent holds two children ids, or null.

Comment: Nested Set Model is probably the better choice in this situation, as the  questions will rarely be altered.  Also, I've seen (and written) code to handle the details of updating the nodes.  It's not hard.

Comment: Nested Set is probably better, I agree, especially if you're doing few updates. In this case, though, I dislike that it allows adding more than two answers.

Answer (score 1):

I think I would do something like this:

```
Table: Questions
int id
string question

Table: Question Answer Map
int questionId
bool answer
int nextQuestion
```

Instead of a bool, you could use an int, char, or string for your answer if the questions are multiple choice.

Comment: I've used this structure many times.  I think you mean nextQuestion....not nextAnswer though.